# Vectors cross products

Tags: geometry, vectors

If "$\vec a\times\vec b=\vec c \times \vec d$" . And 
$\vec a\times \vec c = \vec b \times \vec d$
Then prove that  $\vec a + \vec d = k(\vec b +\vec c)$, where $k$ is some number.

I got as far as proving 
$\vec a - \vec d = k'(\vec b - \vec c) $

But no further progress..

Note that $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are vectors and $k$ is any real no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:$$(\vec a+\vec d)\times(\vec b+\vec c)=\vec a\times\vec b+\vec a\times\vec c+\vec d\times\vec b+\vec d\times\vec c$$

Comment: Ohh how can I miss that.. Thanks anyways